# Python standard output shows hidden characters in emacs

Tags: python, bash, emacs

I wrote a python function that generates a `list` of words. First, it reads a file that consists of words separated by new lines. Depending on the word, it either inserts it into the `list` or inserts a blank space, represented by a tab. Here's a relevant portion of code:

`xclusives1`, `xclusives2`, `dups`, are `list`s.

`generator` is an instance of the class containing the function.

```
def xfile1(self):
        for item1 in self.lines1:
            for item2 in self.lines2:
                if item1 == item2:
                    self.xclusives1.append("\t")
                    self.xclusives2.append("\t")
                    self.dups.append(item1)
                    break
            self.xclusives1.append(item1)
            self.xclusives2.append("\t")
            self.dups.append("\t")
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
            print generator.xclusives2
```

As you can see, I am appending `list`s with tabs and items from the file. I want the output to go to a file, so on the commandline, I do:

`comm.py` is the program name, `test`, `test2` are test inputs.

```
$python comm.py test test2 >commOut
```

Opening up the output file in emacs gives me someething looking like this:

'\t', '\t', '\t', 'aword\n', 'anotherword\n', ...

Every `list` item is surrounded by single quotes, and all the hidden characters show up on emacs, even though the in the original list from which the function obtained the words, the newlines were hidden

How do I make it so that the newlines and tabs are displayed as the proper hidden characters?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I edited it. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you print list it prints the *repr* of all the items. This is so you don't, say, confuse the lists `[1, '1']` and `['1', 1]` (Where `1` is an int and `'1'` is a str)

To fix this, if all of the items are strings, print them joined by `', '`,

```
print ', '.join(generator.xclusives2)
```

Or, if you want to still have the quotes around strings,

```
print "'" + "', '".join(generator.xclusives2) + "'"
```

Note that `str(string) == string`. (`str('Hello world!') == 'Hello world!'`) and `repr(string) != string` (`repr('Hello world!') == "'Hello world!'"`)